# Randomly calling methods from list by chance X

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

I  have 2 questions because I have 2 possible implementations in  mind

I have a list of functions that I have to call pseudo randomly every loop with chance X native way will be:

```cs
void loop() {
 foreach(var func in functions) {
         if(Random.Range(0,X)==1) func();
    }
}
```

1 how to do it optimally? (200/1000 elements in the list chances like `1` in `2,3,4.,15`)

And 2 question its possible to do it in that that every function has different chance to by called?
as possible I mean more optimally that having different List for every chance (I would be only 10-20 unique chances) and running this for every list
AND I DONT want even distribution I know that I X time I would be `+` `-` even but I don't want something like calling second seventh element every loop

What did you try and what were you expecting?

idk what to write in this paragraph its optimization problem.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you start with and what you want to achieve, but it sounds like you are looking for some sort of "weighted random". Please note that "optimization" starts with working code - in current state the question is more like "give me the best solution" as in "anything that works go"... to look more like real optimization question show working code to start with and clarify what metric you need to optimize, ideally with measurements of existing code and corresponding goal values.

Comment: Sounds like you need a class that maps chance weights to ```Action```s.  Something like a ```List<(float weight, Action func)>```...?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sort of logic that I would use. I would start with a list of numbers that represent the chance for each corresponding method. You might do it do they all sum to 1 or so that they are all whole numbers or whatever. Sum all those values and then generate a random number in that range. Sum the values in the list until you get the largest value that is less than or equal to the random value you generated and then execute the method that corresponds to the last number you added.

Alternatively, you could create a list that contained every value in the range. For that, you'd have to use whole numbers for every method. Let's say that you have four methods and they have 1/10, 2/10, 3/10 and 4/10 chance respectively. You could create a dictionary with keys being the numbers from 1 to 10 and values where the methods appear 1, 2, 3 and 4 times respectively. You could then generate a random number in the range 1 to 10 and get the corresponding value for that key in the dictionary. This will be the most optimal solution in use because there's no calculation to be done each but, rather, just a lookup. There's minimal work to be done up front as well.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers here already (weighted chances). I'm copy pasting fragments of my own code as practical implementation.

First simple converting float weight list into normalized chance buckets from 0 to 1 range:

```
        public static void ConvertToNormalizedRanges(IList<float> weights)
        {
            if (weights == null || weights.Count == 0) return;
            var sum = weights.Sum();
            for (var i = 0; i < weights.Count; i++)
            {
                weights[i] /= sum;
            }

            if (weights.Count > 2)
            {
                for (var i = 1; i < weights.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    weights[i] += weights[i - 1];
                }
            }

            weights[weights.Count - 1] = 1f;
        }
```

Index of random bucket calculate from above:

```
        public static int RandomWeightedBucket(IReadOnlyList<float> weights)
        {
            var randomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1f);
            for (var i = 0; i < weights.Count; i++)
            {
                if (randomNumber <= weights[i]) return i;
            }

            return 0;
        }
```